# kubectl version returns error

Tags: linux, kubernetes, centos7, kubectl

I am trying to install a Kubernetes cluster on CentOS 7.3 servers. After some progress I got stuck on getting installing CNI plugin. To install plugin I need to pass a parameter which extracted from "kubectl version" command output. However command gets error when getting the required information, Server version:

```
[root@bigdev1 ~]# kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"6", GitVersion:"v1.6.0", GitCommit:"fff5156092b56e6bd60fff75aad4dc9de6b6ef37", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-03-28T16:36:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.7.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

Actually I started using default documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/) with version kubeadm 1.7.3 (and Docker 17) but got stuck on a check:

```
[root@bigdev1 ~]# kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16
[kubeadm] WARNING: kubeadm is in beta, please do not use it for production clusters.
[init] Using Kubernetes version: v1.7.4
[init] Using Authorization modes: [Node RBAC]
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
[preflight] WARNING: docker version is greater than the most recently validated version. Docker version: 17.03.1-ce. Max validated version: 1.12
[preflight] Starting the kubelet service
[kubeadm] WARNING: starting in 1.8, tokens expire after 24 hours by default (if you require a non-expiring token use --token-ttl 0)
[certificates] Generated CA certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated API server certificate and key.
[certificates] API Server serving cert is signed for DNS names [bigdev1 kubernetes kubernetes.default kubernetes.default.svc kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local] and IPs [10.96.0.1 10.0.109.20]
[certificates] Generated API server kubelet client certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated service account token signing key and public key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy CA certificate and key.
[certificates] Generated front-proxy client certificate and key.
[certificates] Valid certificates and keys now exist in "/etc/kubernetes/pki"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf"
[kubeconfig] Wrote KubeConfig file to disk: "/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf"
[apiclient] Created API client, waiting for the control plane to become ready
```

(waits here forever)

Then I decreased Docker version to 1.12.6 and kubernetes version to 1.6.0
After modifying kubeadm config. Also stopped passing cidr parameter to kubeadm init.

I will be glad if you can give any suggestions to get cleared of this issue or give the result of below command:

kubectl version | base64 | tr -d '\n'

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to concentrate on why kubeadm hangs. Once that it solved, kubectl will work, and you can continue with the CNI plugin...
See e.g. the "troubleshooting" section on the document you're following, or see issues like e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/103

Answer (score 0):

not sure which document your following. I would recommend using the `kubeadm` to configure the cluster.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/

Comment: Exactly this document :)

Comment: any updates on this question. I am also getting exactly that error

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the result of the command:

kubectl version 2>&1| base64 | tr -d '\n'